# html display is bugged in ff/ie (not chrome)

Tags: windows, browser, html

Firefox and IE malfunctioned suddenly on my Win 8.1 system, while chrome works ok. FF/IE display everything like i would expect netscape navigator 2 to do... default fonts and default windows colors only (i think they neglect CSS). Tried FF reinstallation including removal of all data folders and registry entries to no avail, before i realized the problem is deeper by testing IE 11. FF safe mode is off, addons work, flash works. The whole thing started when FF asked if i want to "refresh" it. Don't remember my choice but there was no apparent reason for this dialog to appear (FF wasn't reinstalled or updated at that point, although it was updated recently). Anyone any ideas what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Partial resolution, which fixes FF display, is to go to FF options, find "Override colors specified by the page with your selections above", and set to "never". Although i was not using a high contrast scheme (the default for this option, which i never used before, is "only for high contrast"), windows-browser relation is bugged on my system and FF/IE think i use it. Just switching the color scheme runtime has some immediate effects but after reboot things change so this is not a permanent solution. Btw, i still have no clue what caused this behavior (it started suddenly and unprovoked), and i also have no clue how to fix IE11. Its options under general->appearance don't have effect on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, it could be enumulation modes:

[Controlling WebBrowser Control Compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/)